# SelectableSection Update another Section in Eureka Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, eureka-forms

I have this `SelectableSection` with Images in my Eureka form.

```
        +++ SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>("Τρόπος Αποστολής", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true)) { section in
            section.tag = "troposapostolis"
        }

        <<< ImageCheckRow<String>("speedex"){
            $0.title = "Σταθερή Χρέωση - 3,00€\n SPEEDEX (Για όλη την Ελλάδα)"
            $0.selectableValue = ""
            $0.value = nil
            }.cellSetup { cell, _ in
                cell.trueImage = UIImage(named: "selectedRectangle")!
                cell.falseImage = UIImage(named: "unselectedRectangle")!
            }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                row.title = "speedex"
                row.selectableValue = "selectedspeedex"
            })

        <<< ImageCheckRow<String>("paradosi"){
            $0.title = "Αυθημερόν Παράδοση - 6,00€\n Ισχύει για ορισμένες περιοχές εντός Αττικής. Υποβολή παραγγελίας μέχρι τις 14:00."
            $0.selectableValue = ""
            $0.value = nil
            }.cellSetup { cell, _ in
                cell.trueImage = UIImage(named: "selectedRectangle")!
                cell.falseImage = UIImage(named: "unselectedRectangle")!
            }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                row.title = "paradosi"
                row.selectableValue = "selectedparadosi"
            })
```

And I want to update another section when the user taps any of the above selections. This is the section->custom cell I want to update

```
     +++ Section("summary")
        <<< SummaryPuchaseRow().cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
            cell.merikoSinolo.text = "\(self.realmfunctions.getAmount())€"
            cell.sum.text = "" \\value depending on the image selected
        })
```

So if the user taps the first row on the `SelectableSection` I would like the

```
cell.sum.text = "3"
```

And if the user taps the second row in the `SelectableSection` I would ike the

```
cell.sum.text = "6"
```

Is there any efficient way to do so ?? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me know if my answer has solved your problem, best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use a tag, to get your cell from Form in the `onCellSelection` search for your cell with tag defined, and getting the cell change the value on the control in this case `sum.text`, here is the code

```
+++ SelectableSection<ImageCheckRow<String>>("Τρόπος Αποστολής", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true)) { section in
            section.tag = "troposapostolis"
        }

        <<< ImageCheckRow<String>("speedex"){
            $0.title = "Σταθερή Χρέωση - 3,00€\n SPEEDEX (Για όλη την Ελλάδα)"
            $0.selectableValue = ""
            $0.value = nil
            }.cellSetup { cell, _ in
                cell.trueImage = UIImage(named: "selectedRectangle")!
                cell.falseImage = UIImage(named: "unselectedRectangle")!
            }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                row.title = "speedex"
                row.selectableValue = "selectedspeedex"

               if let summaryRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "important") as? SummaryPuchaseRow
                {
                    if let baseCellSummary = summaryRow.baseCell as? ???? //ATTENTION!!! put here your cell type name
                    {
                        baseCellSummary.sum.text = "3"
                    }
                }
            })

        <<< ImageCheckRow<String>("paradosi"){
            $0.title = "Αυθημερόν Παράδοση - 6,00€\n Ισχύει για ορισμένες περιοχές εντός Αττικής. Υποβολή παραγγελίας μέχρι τις 14:00."
            $0.selectableValue = ""
            $0.value = nil
            }.cellSetup { cell, _ in
                cell.trueImage = UIImage(named: "selectedRectangle")!
                cell.falseImage = UIImage(named: "unselectedRectangle")!
            }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                row.title = "paradosi"
                row.selectableValue = "selectedparadosi"

          if let summaryRow = self.form.rowBy(tag: "important") as? SummaryPuchaseRow
            {
                if let baseCellSummary = summaryRow.baseCell as? ???? //ATTENTION!!! put here your cell type name
                {
                    baseCellSummary.sum.text = "3"
                }
            }
            })
```

And you need setup a tag for your SummaryRow, in this example I use "important" as tag

```
+++ Section("summary")
        <<< SummaryPuchaseRow(tag: "important").cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
            cell.merikoSinolo.text = "\(self.realmfunctions.getAmount())€"
            cell.sum.text = "" \\value depending on the image selected
        })
```

I hope this helps you, best regards